# why python gives garbage value of self.var of this program?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm new to python. I create a GUI with Object-oriented which is shown a simple status bar. when we press a button then the status will be changed (Ready to uploading) for 2 seconds .but python gives a garbage value like PY_VAR0 . and the status does not change. What should I do to solve this error?

```
from tkinter import *



class Status(Tk):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('750x550')
        self.title('OOP With Py')
        


    def varValue(self):
        self.var=StringVar()
        self.var.set('Ready Now')

        return self.var


    def upload(self):
        import time
        self.var.set('Uploading')
        self.l.update()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.var.set('Ready')

    


    def Label(self):
        self.l=Label(self,text=self.varValue(),anchor=W,relief=SUNKEN,font='lucida 20 bold')
        self.l.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)


    def button(self,text):
        Button(self,text=text,command=self.upload).pack()





if __name__=='__main__':
    window=Status()
    window.Label()
    window.varValue()
    # window.upload()
    window.button('Upload')
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should use `textvariable` option instead of `text`:

```py
def Label(self):
    self.l=Label(self,textvariable=self.varValue(),anchor=W,relief=SUNKEN,font='lucida 20 bold')
    self.l.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
```

Second, you should not call `window.varValue()` after `window.Label()` as it will assign new instance of `StringVar()` to `self.var`.  So updating `self.var` will not update `self.l`:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    window=Status()
    window.Label()
    #window.varValue()  ### should not be called
    # window.upload()
    window.button('Upload')
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a textvariable, not text

```
def Label(self):
    self.l=Label(self,textvariable=self.varValue(),anchor=W,relief=SUNKEN,font='lucida 20 bold')
    self.l.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
```

Comment: Thank you. But Why does status not change?